# Performance Issue while using On delete cascading in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Parent Table which is having just the 10 rows,

But their respective child table will have 100K records, for 1 ID in parent table we have 10K record in child table.

When I fire a delete command on parent table it also delete the record from child table, But it takes around 5 minutes to delete all 10K records.

So my question is what is the best practice to delete records from child table when we have cascading effects on the table.

10K records is just an example for some ID we have millions of records to delete.

Comment: Post the execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming SQL Server could make use of an index while deleting, placing an index on the foreign key column in the child table might speed up the deletion.  For example:

```
parent (id, col1, col2, ...)
child  (id, parent_id, ...)

CREATE INDEX ON child (parent_id);
```

Such an index might let SQL Server quickly lookup each child record, given a parent record.

Comment: I have the index on the foreign key column

Comment: Then you should check the query plan for the deletion to see what the holdup is.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

It takes time to delete thousands of rows in a table.  The deletion has to:

- Find the rows to delete.
- Change the data on the data pages.
- Log the changes.
- Modify indexes.
- Execute triggers (if any).
- Delete related rows in other tables (if any).

This can be quite expensive.

Given the low volume of parent ids, I think you can speed this by partitioning the child table by the parent id.  A clustered index on the parent id might also help -- but that might affect insert performance.